# multivariate statistics covariance calculation

Tags: statistics, covariance

What is the co-variance of x and y when x=(-2,0,0,2) and y=(0,1,-1,0)? I would like to clarify how to calculate the co-variance. I think it should be zero in this case but not am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly check your expectations for this small example using the formula for [the sample covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance).

Or, in R:

```
> cov(c(-2,0,0,2), c(0,1,-1,0))
 [1] 0
```